# Read a CSV file in C

Tags: c, csv

I have to read a file in the console in C, the file is a CSV file. My code is the following :

```
printf("Ajouter un site internet \n");
        printf("------------------------------------------\n");
        FILE * curseur = fopen("listess.csv", "a");
        SITES * pSites = calloc(100000, sizeof(SITES));
        int i = 0;
        int iSites = 0;
        int champSites = 0;
        char temp[1000];
        if (curseur != NULL) {
            char c = fgetc(curseur);
            while (c != EOF) {
                printf("%s", (pSites + iSites)->url);
                if (c != '\n' && c != ';') {
                    temp[i] = c;
                    i++;
                }

                else if (c == ';') {
                    temp[i] = '\0';
                    if (champSites == 0) {
                        strcpy((pSites + iSites)->Commune, temp);
                        champSites++;
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    else if (champSites == 1) {
                        strcpy((pSites + iSites)->Insee, temp);
                        champSites++;
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    else if (champSites == 2) {
                        strcpy((pSites + iSites)->url, temp);
                        champSites++;
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    else if (champSites == 3) {
                        strcpy((pSites + iSites)->Population, temp);
                        champSites++;
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    else if (champSites == 4) {
                        strcpy((pSites + iSites)->https, temp);
                        champSites++;
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    else if (champSites == 5) {
                        strcpy((pSites + iSites)->Serveur, temp);
                        champSites++;
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    else if (champSites == 6) {
                        strcpy((pSites + iSites)->Version, temp);
                        champSites++;
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    else if (champSites == 7) {
                        strcpy((pSites + iSites)->Application, temp);
                        champSites++;
                        i = 0;
                    }

                    else if (champSites == 8) {
                        strcpy((pSites + iSites)->VersionApplication, temp);
                        champSites++;
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    else if (champSites == 9) {
                        strcpy((pSites + iSites)->Langage, temp);
                        champSites++;
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    else if (champSites == 10) {
                        strcpy((pSites + iSites)->VersionLangage, temp);
                        champSites++;
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    else if (champSites == 11) {
                        strcpy((pSites + iSites)->Latitude, temp);
                        champSites++;
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    else if (champSites == 12) {
                        strcpy((pSites + iSites)->Longitude, temp);
                        champSites++;
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    iSites++;
                }
                c = fgetc(curseur);
            }
            system("pause");
            fclose(curseur);
        }
```

But I do have any result in the console except the two first lines. 
The file is composed of 13 columns that I declared in a .h file.

The 5 first lines of the csv:

```
Commune;Code Insee;url;Population;https;Serveur;Version du serveur;Application;Version de l'application;Langage;Version du langage;Latitude;Longitude
Argentat;19010;argentat.fr;3042;non;SiteW;2;Inconnue;Inconnue;php;5.3.29;45.100801186828598;1.934640270901890
Canenx-et-Réaut;40064;mairie-info.com;175;non;SiteW;2;Inconnue;Inconnue;php;5.3.29;43.999060134922502;-0.464769980981436
Chaussan;69051;chaussan.fr;972;non;SiteW;2;Inconnue;Inconnue;Inconnue;Inconnue;45.637283899086498;4.634069843807340
Étrez;1154;etrez.fr;803;non;SiteW;2;Inconnue;Inconnue;Inconnue;Inconnue;46.338283686023097;5.192873875680920
Gray ;70279;ville-gray.fr;6016;non;SiteW;2;Inconnue;Inconnue;php;5.2.10;47.432262030641297;5.610925314619960
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]  : Emphasis on MINIMAL

Comment: Please post the 5-6 first lines of your `listess.csv` file.

Comment: ...and `fopen("listess.csv", "a");` should be `fopen("listess.csv", "r");`.

Comment: I added the 5th lines of the csv

Comment: 1. You should update this code in line with your second posted code below
2. A switch statement, on the value of champSites, would make the code much clearer
3. There is much repeated code

It would have been much better to write your algorithm in pseudo-code at a higher level, then we would not get distracted by issues such as the above.

Comment: Are the blank line in your csv file on purpose ?

Comment: I do not have blank line in the csv file, I added these lines there

Comment: BTW your code is overly complicated. You should read the file line by line using [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/?kw=fgets) and decompose each line using the [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/?kw=strtok) function.

Comment: Probably, i'm not an expert in C programmation. That's my 5th program in C.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is overly complicated. Throw it away and base your new code on this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  // declare and initialize your pSites stuff here
  ....
  //

  if (curseur == NULL)
  {
    printf("Can't open file\n");
    return 1;
  }

  int linenumber = 1;
  char buffer[1000];

  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, curseur))
  {
    char *token = strtok(buffer, ";");
    printf("Line %d\n", linenumber++);

    int column = 0;
    while (token != NULL)
    {
      printf("%2d    %s\n", column, token);

      switch (column)
      {
        case 0:
          strcpy((pSites + iSites)->Commune, token);
          break;

        case 1:
          strcpy((pSites + iSites)->Insee, token);
          break;

        case 2:
         .... etc.
      }

      token = strtok(NULL, ";");
      column++;
    }

    iSites++;
  }

  fclose(curseur);
}
```

BTW: instead of writing

```
(pSites + iSites)->Commune
```

you should write the more readable variant:

```
pSites[iSites]->Commune
```

Comment: Than you very much, it works. But I did it so complicated cause the goal of this exercice was to add a website at the end of the csv. To realize stats of the type of the servers (Apache / IIS ...). And to find a website with the name of the city.

Comment: Adding a new line at the end of the CSV is a different problem, but you still can use that code as a base.

Comment: Thank you, it works well :) 
But, how can i can add url now ? Please Sir

Comment: @DylanDELHOMMOIS that's a different question. Ask a new question please.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
                if (champSites == 0) {
                    strcpy((pSites + iSites)->Commune, temp);
                    champSites++;
                    i = 0;
                }
                else if (champSites == 0) {
                    strcpy((pSites + iSites)->Insee, temp);
                    champSites++;
                    i = 0;
                }
```

makes no sense, note that both conditions are `else if(champSites == 0)` which will clearly mean that most of the code is dead (won't ever execute).

Should perhaps be `if 0 ... else if 1 ... else if 2` and so on.